# iOS HTTP Response Clarifications

Tags: iphone, response, httpresponse

I have questions about 'Response' from server.

1. 'content in HTTP Response' is same meaning of 'body of HTTP Response (not head of HTTP Response)'?
2. How to get content or body of HTTP Response?
3. What is diffrence of NSURLResponse and NSHTTPURLResponse?

Comment: Hi bqbqhahabq, you're new here so didn't know that greetings and thanks are not appropriate in a question on Stack Overflow, so I removed them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have first read documentation of apple for [NSHTTPURLResponse](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/search/?q=NSURLResponse)

[1](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/search/?q=NSURLResponse): http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSHTTPURLResponse_Class/Reference/Reference.html  and [NSURLResponse](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/search/?q=NSURLResponse)